# Cell should equal most right hand side filled column value in range - EXCEL

Tags: excel

Ive got an issue register spreadsheet, which is like a punch card system for when a document revision was published.

In the columns `B-M` i have the revision numbers for each document and in column A i want to have a record of the latest revision so it can be refered to quickly. At the moment i manage this by hand but have been trying to find a formal to manage column A for me.

In pseudo code it should be : 
`A2 = the last published number in B2-M2` But ive been struggling to think of the right way to write this with a native spreadsheet function without using VBA / google spreadsheet JS script.

Ive created a dummy spreadsheet here to illustrate the problem : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J6ETdlR2GEg-OeU4hojUe8bmH42zwP1GsQLyinDzHSg/edit#gid=0

Any help would be much apprecaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(99,B2:M2))
```

copied down to suit (assumes rev numbers will not exceed 98 - if text format replace `99` with `"zzz"`).